# How to use LinkedIn API to get Post Analysis Data (Impressions, Reactions, Engagement Rate)?

Tags: linkedin-api, posts, impressions

When you have posted something on LinkedIn and click on "show statistics" you can see several KPIs (e.g. Impressions, Engagement Rate, Reactions, etc.).

I feel pretty dumb to ask this here, because I would have expected to find this well documented in the official documentation, but unfortunateley it is not. (or am I really that dumb?)

So my question is: How can I retrieve these KPIs using the LinkedIn API?

I was able to pull a list of all posts, but I am not able to find any information of how to get the KPIs too.

Thank you very much in advance for you help!

All the best
blue

Comment: What is "the API"? I would recommend that you ask the maintainer of that API for help

Comment: Hey, very sorry to not mention the API. This post is about the LInkedIn API. - Somehow thought the link posted here ( https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a526157 ) would lead to something like a special section in stack overflow that is explicitly for linkedIn. - looks like it doesn't. - i added more tags and mentioned linkedin in the original post.